# Open the default browser in Ruby

Tags: ruby, browser

In Python, you can do this:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open_new("http://example.com/")
```

It will open the passed in url in the default browser

Is there a ruby equivalent?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

### Cross-platform solution:

First, install the [Launchy](http://www.copiousfreetime.org/projects/launchy/) gem:

```
$ gem install launchy
```

Then, you can run this:

```
require 'launchy'

Launchy.open("http://stackoverflow.com")
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work with data urls. (Have you got it to work with data urls? If not, have another suggestion?)

Comment: In theory, it should work with any scheme registered with the operating system. Data URIs typically aren't registered with the OS.

Comment: Can you tell me if i can check or not if the opened url using launchy is closed or terminated or not? @RyanMcGeary

Comment: @deadman nope - although you could use javascript or a plugin to call a sever which tells the program (probably overkill)

Comment: 2016/6/17 - link broken - dunno if it is just temporarily down, gone now, or moved. https://github.com/copiousfreetime/launchy works though.

Answer (score 35):

This should work on most platforms:

```
link = "Insert desired link location here"
if RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os'] =~ /mswin|mingw|cygwin/
  system "start #{link}"
elsif RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os'] =~ /darwin/
  system "open #{link}"
elsif RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os'] =~ /linux|bsd/
  system "xdg-open #{link}"
end
```

Comment: This is great, thanks! Just don't forget to forget to quote those strings in case there are metacharacters which would confuse the shell—an & in a URL query string is a classic example. Wrap the URL in single quotes for Mac, Linux, and BSD; double quotes for Windows. On Windows: an extra pair of double quotes are required (_i.e._, `system "start \"\" \"#{link}\""`) because of a quirk in the way `start` handles quoted arguments.

Answer (score 32):

Mac-only solution:

```
system("open", "http://stackoverflow.com/")
```

or

```
`open http://stackoverflow.com/`
```

Answer (score 9):

Simplest Win solution:

```
`start http://www.example.com`
```

Answer (score 8):

Linux-only solution

```
system("xdg-open", "http://stackoverflow.com/")
```

Answer (score 4):

This also works:

```
system("start #{link}")
```

Comment: Note, this is Windows-only solution.

Answer (score 3):

Windows Only Solution:

```
require 'win32ole'
shell = WIN32OLE.new('Shell.Application')
shell.ShellExecute(...)
```

[Shell Execute on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774148.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the 'os' gem: https://github.com/rdp/os to let your operating system (in the best case you own your OS, meaning not OS X) decide what to do with an URL.

Typically this will be a good choice.

```
require 'os'

system(OS.open_file_command, 'https://stackoverflow.com')
# ~ like `xdg-open stackoverflow.com` on most modern unixoids,
# but should work on most other operating systems, too.
```

**Note** On windows, the argument(s?) to `system` need to be escaped, see comment section. There should be a function in Rubys stdlib for that, feel free to add it to the comments and I will update the answer.

Comment: The only solution that worked for me with various params in the url

Comment: OS.open_file_command internally does the same as @user1931928's answer. And it has the same problem with quotes pointed out in the comments

Comment: @BasilPeace good to know. I guess the `os` gem is better maintained than user1931928's answer though ;)
Not having research time now, but I guess `Shellwords` would be the answer wrt to escaping, right? I'll gladly add a hint to my answer.

Comment: @BasilPeace Are you sure, though? As I pass as **second argument** to the `system` call. Thats pretty different from the case where string interpolation is used.

Comment: @Felix, I ran into the issue under Windows, with URLs containing an ampersand (`&`). Looks like `os` gem didn't escape them and just passed them to `cmd` (or `start`?). And the latter considered `&` as a command separator

Comment: I chose Launchy, no issues so far

Comment: @Felix, uh, are you saying that I incorrectly blame `os` gem? The problem is not in there, but in your `system` call?

Comment: @BasilPeace Peace. I did not blame anybody. Please share with me where the `os` gem did not escape the URL. In the answer I give here, the URL is handled by "system", `os` is just used to return a string (the name of the command). I do not own a windows license, but you are also suggesting that `system("start", "https://stackoverflow.com&evilcommand")`  (important: two arguments!) will execute `evilcommand` in Windows? Then it is indeed something to look for into `Kernel.system`.

Comment: @Felix, yes. https://imgur.com/a/oaAhxL9

Comment: @BasilPeace okay, thanks. I will update the description. Smells a bit like a but to me, but cannot judge.

Answer (score 0):

If it's windows and it's IE, try this: http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.com/search/label/watir also check out Selenium ruby: http://selenium.rubyforge.org/getting-started.html

HTH

Comment: The point was that you don't have to guess what the default browser is. If it was IE, there'd be no question of what to do.