# Can not open localhost by running Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, watir, system-calls

I am trying to run a ruby script in rails application using system call, like

```
def runSystemCall
    system("ruby /path/to/ruby/script/watir.rb localhost:3000/articles/14")
end
```

and `watir.rb`:

```
def watir(url)
    bb = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
    bb.goto "#{url[0]}"
end

watir(ARGV)
```

when running this in rails application, a browser opened and stay in a status of `Waiting for localhost...`, until error

```
.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/protocol.rb:158:in `rescue in rbuf_fill': Net::ReadTimeout (Net::ReadTimeout)
```

loaded the website `localhost:3000/articles/14` opened.
Dose anyone know why?

and, when run this in a terminal

```
$ ruby /path/to/ruby/script/watir.rb localhost:3000/articles/14
```

a browser opened and open website `localhost:3000/articles/14`
That's what I expected.

Comment: Have you run your rails server before?

Comment: Yes, rails server is running all the time.
when use other url like www.google.com instead of localhost:3000/articles/14, this issue not happen

Comment: Follow this link   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152699/open-the-default-browser-in-ruby

Comment: I guess Launchy is for running a broswer like chrome or firefox, what I want is run a .rb script, in this script will include some watir code wich will open chrome to open localhost:3000/articles/14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your local server is single threaded. That means it can only handle one request at a time. If one local request wants to load an other page from the same local server, than you need at least two local threads.

Comment: Yes, I use gem thin, then thin start -p 3001
it works.